# Fetch index name from alias during ingest in elasticsearch ingest plugin java

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-indices, ingest

I am using Elasticsearch v7.9 and need to get index name during ingest instead of alias name.

**Alias name** = employees_prod and **Index Name** = employees

```
POST /employees_prod/_doc?pipeline=test-pipeline&refresh
{
  "name": "Quick Brown Fox",
  "created_date": "2021-04-12T19:45:19Z"
}
```

When I pass alias name for document creation as above,  I get alias name when using [ingestDocument.getSourceAndMetadata()](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/ingest/IngestDocument.java#L707).get("_index") during ingest in elasticsearch ingest plugin.

Is there a way to get index name instead of alias name?

I have tried to set dynamic value in pipeline as below to get the index name. But it doesn't work for me.

```
PUT /_ingest/pipeline/test-pipeline
{
  "description": "ES pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "test_ingest_processor": {
        "field": [
          "test_type:test_key",
        ]
      },
     "set": {
        "description": "Set Index value",
        "field": "_index",
        "value": "{{_index}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any solution for this?